# Expandable View with horizontally scrollable images

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I want to have a view like the image shown below i.e. after expanding the view it should show the images with horizontally scrollable.

[image]

Comment: why don't you use a ScrollView for the images

Comment: I need it in something like expandable view

Comment: yeah i got your point. so what about using an ExpandableListView with a ScrollView as a child view which will contain the images.

Comment: i don't have any idea about implementing that

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by follwoing this app

check it out here
https://github.com/sivailango/ExpandableListView-RecylerChildItems